# How to read xt: tagged fields from Atom feeds?

Tags: c#, atom-feed

I'm trying to collect some information from a Atom formatted feed and display it on my web page. But I need to read some fields marked with the (exclude_target) `xt:` property, but as far as I read, they are hidden from the query so I can't reach them.

So the question is:

Is it possible to read/fetch these fields?

If yes, how?

Right now I'm using a SyndicationFeed to load the stream and fetch the other accessible properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googeling and reading allover i realized that even though the xt: tag is a tag it also works just like a namespace so i ended up using LINQ to XML to read it like this:

```
var XmlContainer = XElement.Load(url);

XNamespace nsXt = "http://xstream.dk/";
var Elements = from item in XmlContainer.Descendants("item")
               select new {
                       Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                       Year = item.Elements(nsXt + "details").Value,
               };
```

return Elements.ToList();